# same rpm package shows different file permissions on different machines?

Tags: installation, file-permissions, packaging, rpm, rhel

`rpm -qlvp package.rpm` shows permissions of some executable files as `750` (i.e. `rwxr-x---`) as intended and defined in the spec with the `%attr`directive, on the building machine.

when copied to the target test machine, the same command on the same file shows the default `755` (i.e. `rwxr-xr-x`). These are indeed the permissions of the installed files.

I can't find anything on the net to explain the mystery. Any ideas?

both machines are RHEL 5.7 virtual machines BTW.

Comment: Can you show us your spec file please?

Comment: @davka, Can't say that your question is clearly stated. Is this the first time that the package was installed on both systems? If not, then the original file permissions might be in play. Does `rpm -Vp package.rpm` show evidence that the systems file are different from the original package?

Answer (score -1):

Check you umask settings on both systems, maybe they're different for some reason.